# updating/setting multiple values in lookup field through powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I'm trying to set multiple values to lookup column.
    I can get it to set one value but multiple values don't work

```
see below

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection] $itemValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue] $lookupvalue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue

$lookupvalue.LookupId = 1

$lookupvalue.LookupId = 2

$itemValues.Add($lookupvalue)

$CMRSItems["Event Type"] = $itemValues
$CMRSItems.Update()
```

I was expecting the LookupID 1 and 2 to update but it doesn't.
When i specify LookupId = 1 it works

What am i doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance

### updating multivalues

```
$lookupvalue = GetLookUpValues -val $number
#Write-Host $lookupvalue 

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection] $itemValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue] $lookupvalue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue 


   #sample lookup values adding to collection: 
   #1;#Open
   #2;#Closed

$itemValues.Add($lookupvalue)

$CMRSItems["Event Type"] = $itemValues;
    $CMRSItems.Update();
```

Getting error : Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid look-up value

Comment: On your update: You create a collection, you add an object and assign the collection to the field. But nowhere do you set the LookupID on the object ;), which I think would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create two objects of LookUpValue and add to the collection. Right now you are setting LookupID twice on the same object, overwriting the first assignment.

```
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection] $itemValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection

  [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue]    $lookupvalue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue

  [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue]    $lookupvalue2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue

$lookupvalue.LookupId = 1

$lookupvalue2.LookupId = 2

 $itemValues.Add($lookupvalue)
 $itemValues.Add($lookupvalue2)
```

Also in your new example you seem to overwrite your $lookupvalue

```
$lookupvalue = GetLookUpValues -val $number
#Write-Host $lookupvalue 

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection] $itemValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection
#[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue] $lookupvalue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue #This row creates a new empty lookupvalue, overwriteing the one from line 1

$itemValues.Add($lookupvalue)

$CMRSItems["Event Type"] = $itemValues;
$CMRSItems.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks Rob just missed that..But when i try adding dynamic values to lookupid to update multi values i get an error.
I'll post it soon

Comment: Robert I have added the code im using to update multi vakues to my original post.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rob for the update.But its only updating the last value.I'm sending 3 values to update but only the last value is being updated.Any ideas

Comment: Also When i hard code the multivalues it works.:(

Comment: I do also get error:-Cannot convert value "Event Type" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format." Some of the values im updating is sinple and some are mutli valued.Im sure i'm sending the right format

Comment: After some changes i don't get error : Error: "Input string was not in a correct format." Anymore but i can't get to update multi values.So when i send values "1,2,4" only let last value 4 gets updated

Answer (score 0):

Add toString when updating the lookup field as shown below:

```
$CMRSItems["Event Type"] = $itemValues.ToString();
```